# ASP.NET Treeview D

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a treeview like this

```
<asp:TreeView ID="MyTree" runat="server">
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Red">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Green">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Blue" />
            </asp:TreeNode>

            <asp:TreeNode Text="Green 1">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Blue 1" />
            </asp:TreeNode>

        </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

The output is

```
Red
   Green
   Green 1
```

Is it possible to display like this?

```
Red
   Green         Green 1
```

I'm planning to use css adapters, but it seems have bugs in cascading treeview.

It would be great if someone can help me using css styles. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult introduce, how must presented items 3 level in TreeView on your vision. I think you may try use [asp:Menu](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/Menu.aspx).

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, I was planning to do that, but the css adapters has too many bugs.